# Why is my function returning nonetype even as I'm returning a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, nonetype

I'm making a code for DMOJ challenge CCC '06 J1:

```
b = [
    ["1", 461],
    ["2", 431],
    ["3", 420],
    ["4", 0]
]

dr = [
    ["1", 130],
    ["2", 160],
    ["3", 118],
    ["4", 0]
]

s = [
    ["1", 100],
    ["2", 57],
    ["3", 70],
    ["4", 0]
]

de = [
    ["1", 167],
    ["2", 266],
    ["3", 75],
    ["4", 0]
]

#Lists with order types
    #b = burgers, dr = drinks, s = side orders, de = desserts
    
brg = int(input())
sord = int(input())
drk = int(input())
dess = int(input())

def cbrg():
    for i in range(brg):
        calb = b[brg-1][1]
        return print(calb)

def csord():
    for i in range(sord):
        cals = s[sord-1][1]
        return print(cals)

def cdrk():
    for i in range(drk):
        caldr = dr[drk-1][1]
        return print(caldr)

def cdess():
    for i in range(dess):
        calde = de[dess-1][1]
        return print(calde)
```

I've tried to use the return command with only the "calde", with "print(calde)", and I'm still getting a nonetype, and if I try to use "return int(calde), I get an error saying that the "int()" command cannot be applied to "NoneType".

Comment: The issue is `return print()`. Print returns `None` on it's own, you should `print` _or_ `return` _or_ print then return, or even return from the function then print that value outside the function, but not `return print`

Comment: Do you want to print a value or do you want to return a value? If you want both, then first print, then return the variable. Explain more about what you are wanting this flow to be, and we can help more with the code. It's definite though that you don't want return the output of print since that is nonsense.

Comment: Honestly, this code and some of the situations you're describing don't make much sense. To start with, the functions are never called, but more importantly, unconditional `return`s are almost never what you want. And what values are you inputting? If they're less than 1, the ranges will be empty and the functions will return `None` implicitly. You need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code, example input, expected output, and actual output -- or if you get an error, the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] for more tips.

Comment: Related, maybe duplicates: [Why is this printing 'None' in the output?](/q/28812851/4518341), [What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?](/q/7129285/4518341)

Comment: To be clear, `return calde` *should* work, and I can't see how `int(calde)` could fail since `calde` *should* always be an `int` already.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the return value of `print` is always `None`
To demonstrate this :

```py
>>> foo = print("Evidence!")
Evidence!
>>> print(foo)
None
>>> type(foo)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

What you probably meant to do is print the value and *then* return it, for example :

```py
>>> def print_and_return(x):
...     print(x)
...     return x
...
>>> some = print_and_return(10)
10
>>> some
10
```

Furthermore, that code can be refactored to this :

```py
ITEMS = [[461, 431, 420, 0], [100, 57, 70, 0], [130, 160, 118, 0], [167, 266, 75, 0]]


def get_calorie_count(orders):
    return sum(item[order - 1] for item, order in zip(ITEMS, orders))


print("Your total Calorie count is", get_calorie_count(int(input()) for _ in range(4)))
```